# What language are NoSQL databases typically written in?

Tags: programming-languages, nosql

I have an interest in creating a NoSQL database system for a school project and I am curious as to which languages are the different examples of NoSQL database systems are written in. If there is a majority leader, why is that language the favorite? And if there is more involved in the creation, such as different layers (of a stack), that information would be helpful as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Why to create a new NoSQL. Isn't better to invest energy in  application development?

Comment: Just trying something new. I did that already for a different project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently they are mostly written in Java, ([Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)/[HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) etc) but there is nothing that makes writing them in another language harder or impractical.
I think the reason is that most of these come from open source background, which is mostly developed in java.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is written in [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/). Erlang is really good for distributed systems.

It seems that also [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) is written in Erlang.

Comment: Erlang is written to support distributed systems from the beginning. That means the support for distributed computing is not part of a library that you need to load but seemlessly integrated into the language.

Answer (score 0):

Ayende's [RavenDB](http://www.ravendb.net/) is written in C# (but it's the only one that I heard of that's written in C#).